# Improving SPI transfer speed

Tags: c++, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, spi, ioctl

I am trying to send constant and large amount of bytes with SPI from a Linux embedded system -- am335x (Beaglebone: pocketbeagle version). Thing is, I am trying to increase its transfer rate.

Currently, I am accessing SPI through user-space with the following configuration on spidev (ioctl calls):

```
// SPI init -- (const char *device, int mode, int bits, int speed)
retv = spi_bus.spi_init(LCD_SPI_DEVICE,0,8,100000000);
```

It's slow! I haven't measured the mb/s, but even at 100MHz it's not sending the right amount.

I read somewhere that the DMA is automatically called when using the mcSPI driver. However, I am not really sure if it applies to user-space drivers such as spidev.

My question is: How can I increase the MB/s transfer data for SPI?

Things I have thought about so far:

1) Look for a kernel=space driver instead of using spidev.

2) Increase the word length.

Not sure though, what would you recommend to significantly increase the transfer rate of SPI?

Comment: What is `spi_bus`? Use POSIX functions and linux uapi: `open` and `ioctl` with `SPI_IOC_MESSAGE` and other in [linux/spidev.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/spi/spidev.h#L121). Does `ioctl(..,  SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ, ....)` gives the same result? If so, I guess your hardware doesn't support such speeds or you should write your own kernel module to interface the spi.

Comment: I would suggest to use BeagleBone **PRUs**. There is a [Google Summer of Code project](https://github.com/chanakya-vc/PRU-I2C_SPI_master/wiki#introduction) that developed a device driver on the ARM side and firmware code on the PRU side to manage SPI. It claims transfer speeds of up to 7Mhz. By using PRUs it will also save cpu cycles and reduce load on the main processor.

Comment: @luigif Yes I thought about that, bitbanging with PRUs. But thing is, they are not fast enough. 7MHz is quite slow for my application. I need at least the 40MHz (ideally 48MHz) that I am trying to achieve — which is theoretically the max frequency on the beaglebone’s SPI.

Comment: @LuisCruz, DMA will be used only if the data is more than 160 bytes (as per McSPI).  Userspace driver Spidev will use mcSPI platform driver internally.

Comment: Pretty sure the maximum SPI clock is 16 MHz on your board